# Eclipse - Maven Installation Error

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to install Maven Plugin for Eclipse , but i am geting this error .

I am using

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604            Version of Eclipse .

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.20110804-1717)
  Software currently installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Maven Integration for Eclipse 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
    This version of m2eclipse cannot be installed on top of the already installed m2eclipse. Uninstall the previous version of m2eclipse and try the install again. 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.maven.ide.eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.20110804-1717)
    To: bundle org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.100.20110804-1717]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.1.20110112-1712 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.1.20110112-1712)
    To: org.maven.ide.eclipse [0.12.1.20110112-1712]
```

please refer to the screen shot of the error given below

http://imageshack.us/f/823/eclipsse.jpg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply uninstall m2eclipse version 0.12.x and retry installation. You are essentially trying to install both m2e and m2eclipse (read: older m2e) together.

My Eclipse JDT and m2e versions are:

```
Eclipse Java Development Tools  3.7.0.v20110520-0800
m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.0.20110607-2117
```

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

In my case, installing "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer) did the trick.